# how to access Default PDF template in rails 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI Everybody, 
               In my application I want to access the information from different tables of the database & print that information on the default PDF template.I generally use prawn & prawn_to plug-in for normal PDF generation & it works fine always, but this time I confused how to print the information on the default template.I am trying to do this on Redmine application & scenario is like this I have developed four different plugins & trying to access these plugins data on fifth plug-in.If any body have any idea will save my day.
 Thanks always

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this gem can help you out: https://github.com/joseicosta/odf-report
It works great for generating odf reports using templates, and they can easily be converted into pdf

Comment: Thanks Sebastian I will try to use this & hope it will work fine,Thanks for your help